# Switching from one view controller to another in the same container view

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have two view controllers: `ViewControllerA` and `ViewControllerB`. `ViewControllerA` is added to a container view and it has button. On button tap, `ViewControllerB` should replace `ViewControllerA`. How can I do that? The problem is that button is located inside `ViewControllerB` and not in the main view controller.

Main `ViewController`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    weak var currentViewController: UIViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.currentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Verify")
        self.currentViewController!.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addChildViewController(self.currentViewController!)
        self.initializeFirstScreen(subView: self.currentViewController!.view, toView: self.containerView)

        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func initializeFirstScreen(subView:UIView, toView parentView:UIView){

        parentView.addSubview(subView)

        var viewBindingDict = [String: AnyObject]()
        viewBindingDict["subView"] = subView
        parentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[subView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewBindingDict))
        parentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[subView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewBindingDict))
    }

    func switchToValidate(){

        let newViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Validate")

        //this line throws error
        //fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
        newViewController!.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addChildViewController(newViewController!)
        initializeFirstScreen(subView: (newViewController?.view)!, toView: self.containerView)

    }
}
```

`ViewControllerA`:

```
class VerifyViewController: UIViewController {

    let mainViewController = ViewController()    

    @IBAction func VerifyNumber(){

        self.switchScreens()

    }


    func switchScreens(){

        mainViewController.switchToValidate()

    }
}
```

`switchToValidate` throws the following error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: We need some code for help you

Comment: try this and let me know.

 self.currentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Verify") as! VerifyViewController
 self.currentViewController.mainViewController = self

Comment: this part is unclear self.currentViewController.mainViewController = self currentViewController does not have mainViewController

Comment: add lines of code given in my comment to viewDidLoad of ViewController class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm struggling a little bit in understanding your code.

If the requirement is to maintain the button within `ViewControllerA`, you should inject a reference of the main view controller in it. In `ViewControllerA` you are creating a new instance of `ViewController`.

So, within `ViewController`, instead of doing (you are creating a brand new controller here):

```
let viewController = ViewController()
```

you need to have something like this:

```
weak var mainViewController: ViewController?
```

In `viewDidLoad` you can inject that property within `ViewControllerA` like:

```
if let viewControllerA = 
    self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Validate") as? ViewControllerA {
    viewControllerA.mainViewController = self
    // other code here
}
```

Now, in `ViewControllerA`, you have a reference to the main controller and you can just switch to the other controller.

Few notes:

- `super.viewDidLoad()` should be called as the first instruct when overriding `viewDidLoad`
- prefer `if let` (or `guard`) syntax to `!` in order to deal with optionals. Obviously unless is necessary.